# Prestashop custom layout for specific category

Tags: smarty, prestashop

Can I have a specific **category layout** for selected categories? The detail page will be the same, I need to get a custom tpl file.

Thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty easy to do: override the category controller to set the template.

```
class CategoryController extends CategoryControllerCore {

    // array with the selected categories
    private $customCategories = array(1, 3);

    public function init() {
        parent::init();

        if (in_array($this->category->id, $this->customCategories)) {
            $this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'category-custom.tpl');
        }
    }

}
```

Here you wouldn't be able to change the selected categories from the back office, but it would be easy to do with a module.