# Prestashop create custom layout for specific categories

Tags: html, css, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to create different layouts for some categories for a client. I've found some solutions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875349/prestashop-custom-layout-for-specific-category) but it's an old answer and also i need some more details.

I'm using Prestashop 1.6.0.9 and i want to create a custom-product-list.tpl file to change the layout and add some small features (get products description, get all products images etc).

Has anyone solved this before? I don't mind for a beautiful well-structured code because the price is pretty low. If it's easy and fast with hardcoded, i will prefer it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: so, did you try to code it or you just need that work will be done without your    participation? Answer that you provided already have idea and code, in your case, if you need to replace only product-list.tpl, use `{if $category->id == $your_id} ... include custom product list file here...{/if}` in category.tpl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be many solutions, but the most used are these.

### 1. Edit theme files (preferred)

Prestashop Category template is in the file `themes/[yourtheme]/category.tpl`.

You can edit it placing some code like this:

`YOUR_ID` - integer, the ID of the category.

```
{if isset($category) && isset($category->id) && $category->id == YOUR_ID}

    {* your custome code *}

{else}

    {* place all default category.tpl code here *}

{/if}
```

Also Category template includes `themes/[yourtheme]/product-list.tpl` and else files you can find in code. You can change these `.tpl` files accordingly.

### 2. Override Category controller.

You can override the Category controller and make it use any other template file, not only `themes/[yourtheme]/category.tpl`.

2.1 Make a file `override/controllers/front/CategoryController.php` with the code like this:

```
<?php

class CategoryController extends CategoryControllerCore
{
    public function initContent()
    {
        /* loading the default code */
        parent::initContent();

        /* please add all categories ID for which you want to use this custom template */
        $custom_categories = array(1, 3);

        if (isset($this->category) && in_array($this->category->id, $custom_categories))
        {
            /* please change the file name 'category-1.tpl' 
            to any other file name you want to use in your theme directory,
            i. e. themes/[yourtheme]/category-1.tpl */
            $this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'category-1.tpl');
        }
    }
{
}
```

2.2 Make a file `themes/[yourtheme]/category-1.tpl` (or with else name) with your custom code.

2.3 *Optional*. For security reasons copy any `index.php` file from any folder *except the root folder* to the folders you have created (if created) while making the 2.1 part.

Comment: Thank you very much. Both solutions worked but i used the 2nd one Override Category controller. Seems more abstract to me ^^.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for this too but for prestashop 1.7.
Here is my solution if it can help.

Overriding the CategoryController so we can have different template for each category.
And then we just need to create a folder with the category friendly url name + category.tpl
If the file doesn't exist it uses the default one.

```
    <?php
class CategoryController extends CategoryControllerCore
{
    public function initContent()
    {

        parent::initContent();
        $this->setTemplate($this->getTpl());

        //$this->setTemplate('category.tpl');
        //$this->setTemplate('module:categoryController/views/templates/front/display.tpl');
    }
    protected function getTpl()
    {
      // it seems in prestashop 1.7, the search folder for setTemplate is myThemeFolder/templates/
      // we set the default layout if there's not custom files
      $layout = $this->template; // which here is   $this->template : 'catalog/listing/category.tpl'

      if ($parents = $this->category->getParentsCategories(Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT')))
        {

            foreach ($parents as $parent)
            {
                $parent = (object) $parent;
                if (isset($parent->link_rewrite))
                {
                    // server full path for file_exists. Example : /var/www/vhosts/myvps.address.net/website.folder/themes/myThemeFolder/templates/layouts/categories/women/category.tpl
                    $categoryLayoutOverride_path = _PS_THEME_DIR_ . 'templates/layouts/categories/' . $parent->link_rewrite . '/category.tpl';

                    // for custom template on a particular category, we must have a folder with the friendly url name of the category + category.tpl, in myThemeFolder/templates/layouts/categories folder/
                    // then the layout path value must start at root of templates folder like this : layouts/categories/(category friendly url)/category.tpl
                    $categoryLayoutOverride = 'layouts/categories/' . $parent->link_rewrite . '/category.tpl';

                    if (file_exists($categoryLayoutOverride_path))
                    {
                        $layout = $categoryLayoutOverride;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $layout;
    }
}
?>
```